# GSM Phone for Texting on Ubuntu Server

Tags: sms, gammu

I am building a server for my flying club, I have everything working except sending texts.
I always get same error:

```
Error sending SMS: No SMSC number given. Provide it manually or use the       one configured in phone. (EMPTYSMSC[31])
```

Using Gammu, although I have set the SMSC number in my config file (/etc/gammu-smsdrc)

Heres the lines from my file:

```
[smsd]
Smsc = +447785016005
Service = files
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong please, everything else like Phone_id is actioned, but not the SMSC number.

Thanks, Clock.

Comment: What Gammu version do you use? The SMSC configuration directive was added quite recently (in 1.36.2).

Comment: Aha! I got version 1.33.0 from the ubuntu repos with apt-get - that explains that then, presumably you can tell me where to get the latest.

Comment: However it is now working???? I switched the phone off and on again, it's a ZTE T96, I changed the Phone connection from 3G to Automatic, it still displays 3G so that is not why, I issued a dmesg | grep ttyUSB command and found the phone had issues on USB0 so I changed the config to /dev/ttyUSB1, I also deleted the .gammurc file from ~root.......

Comment: I have no idea WHY it is working, but, I need to know really.... I also used "comgt -x -d /dev/ttyUSB1" to connect the phone (cant remember who told me to do this) and linked /dev/ttyUSB1 to /dev/modem, I don't know if this is why it is working. I remain confused but happier that it is working. Any ideas still greatly appreciated, Clock. PS. "gammu --identify" still returns "Probably phone not connected? What????

Comment: Maybe the phone has downloaded SMSC from the network. It's hard to guess without debug log, see http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/

Comment: I just mailed over some of the log file to you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the `SMSC` setting was added quite recently (in Gammu 1.36.2), so if you are using older version it can't work.

Generally when Gammu can not get SMSC number from the SIM card (many of them do not have it stored), you have few options:

- pass the number using [`-smscnumber`](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/#cmdoption-gammu-smscnumber) when creating/sending the message
- store the SMSC number in the SIM card using [`setsmsc`](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/#cmdoption-gammu-arg-setsmsc)
- in SMSD use recently introduced [`SMSC`](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/config.html#option-SMSC) configuration directive

Comment: Thanks Michal - I am using playSMS to send the messages, so I cannot use -smscnumber I think.. The SIM does store the SMSC number and you should see from the log I sent you this morning that gammu is now retrieving it. The system works now, but I am not sure why.... So unless you see anything odd in the log file that you think I should act on, I think we have a solution now - Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: `setsmsc` didn't work (Error: `Empty entry.`) and that's a shame, I must use `smscnumber` (thanks a lot for that it took my hours to find it), do you know how I can store the smscnumber on the sim card?.